# Getting the text selected in a dropdownbox using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a typescript controller with a public variable below

```
public selectedTopicValue;
```

I am able to populate my dropdownbox with the code below and it works very well

```
        <div class="selectTopic">
           <select id="cTopic" name="cTopic" ng-model="cuc.selectedTopicValue"  
            ng-options="item.topicId as item.topicDescription for item in cuc.getData">               
           </select>
         </div>
```

Here is the model I am using for my dropdownbox

```
         public class TopicsModel
            {
                public string topicId { get; set; }
                public string topicDescription { get; set; }
            }
```

Anytime I select an Item in the dropdownbox, I want to get the actual text i.e
topicdescription and not the value. selectedTopicValue which is my ng-model
is always returning the topicId (0-7)

How do I change this such that ng-model will always be the topicDescription?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options="item.topicDescription for item in cuc.getData"`